Retrieve category names and colors from many emails using win32com python
I would like to retrieve the category names and colors from many emails using win32com python.
I have full admin rights on the emails.
For some reason I do not understand, the output provides the John colors, which is my email for all the mails.
What should I change in the function below, in order to retrieve the categories of the other mails? I already spent a lot of time with chatGTP and it doesn't help at all.

{'john@gmx.com': {'ColorJohn': 3, 'Red category': 1, 'Blue category':
8, 'Purple category': 9, 'Green category': 5, 'Orange category': 2,
'Yellow category': 4}, 'isa@gmx.com': {'ColorJohn': 3, 'Red category':
1, 'Blue category': 8, 'Purple category': 9, 'Green category': 5,
'Orange category': 2, 'Yellow category': 4}, 'nora@gmail.com':
{'ColorJohn': 3, 'Red category': 1, 'Blue category': 8, 'Purple
category': 9, 'Green category': 5, 'Orange category': 2, 'Yellow
category': 4}}

def get_category_colors(emails):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    category_colors_all = {}

    for user_email in emails:
        recipient = outlook.CreateRecipient(user_email)
        shared_calendar = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9) 
        categories = shared_calendar.Session.Categories
        category_colors = {}
        for category in categories:
            category_colors[category.Name] = category.Color
        category_colors_all[user_email] = category_colors

    return category_colors_all
    
emails = ['john@gmail.com', 'isa@gmail.com', 'nora@gmx.com']

# Example usage
category_colors = get_category_colors(emails)
print(category_colors)

I am expecting this output:

{'john@gmx.com': {'ColorJohn': 3, 'Red category': 1, 'Blue category':
8, 'Purple category': 9, 'Green category': 5, 'Orange category': 2,
'Yellow category': 4}, 'isa@gmx.com': {'ColorIsa': 4, 'Red category':
1, 'Blue category': 8, 'Purple category': 9, 'Green category': 5,
'Orange category': 2, 'Yellow category': 4}, 'nora@gmail.com':
{'ColorNora': 7, 'Red category': 1, 'Blue category': 8, 'Purple
category': 9, 'Green category': 5, 'Orange category': 2, 'Yellow
category': 4}}


Your code always retrieves categories from the primary Outlook store - the Session property (Namespace object) is global and is the same object retrieved from Application.Session.
categories = shared_calendar.Session.Categories

Not much you can do about that in the Outlook Object Model. If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, it exposes categories on the store level as well. Or you can access the hidden (associated message) in the Calendar that stores the categories as XML in one of its properties.

Here is quick example
def get_email_info(items):
    for item in items:
        if item.Categories:
            print(item.Categories)
            print(item.Subject)
            print(item.ReceivedTime)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import win32com.client

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        "outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    emails = inbox.Items
    get_email_info(emails)

